# Minimize # of bins when packing n items with bins of max capacity W while also minimizing bin space wasted?

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy, bin-packing

So, you want to pack ***n*** items with varying weights ***w_i*** into bins with a max weight capacity of ***W***.

It's like your generic bin packing problem but the following constraint makes it different (probably easier):

1. The items are given in the order *w_1,..., w_i, ...,w_n*, and **the item that comes first must be placed before considering the next item**.

And finally, you also want to minimize the space wasted in each bin. This is defined by an objective function -- the general behavior in layman's terms is this: if only less than or equal 5% of the bin is wasted, it's fine by you and its not recorded. Otherwise, if greater than 5% is wasted, it's recorded and you don't want that.

Goal: to minimize the number of bins used while also minimizing the space wasted. **The priority is to minimize the number of bins first.**

What is the best algorithm/approach for this?

---

I'm not really sure if this is bin packing problem variant, but I asked it as if it was anyway. If you guys know a better fit of which problem it's a variant to, please let me know.

Also, I want to know all the possible approaches I could use to tackle this kind of problem (dynamic programming or greedy approach).

Some unimplemented attempts at a solution:

1. I tried the greedy approach similar to First Fit algorithm, but it doesn't always get the optimal solution. At times, the space wasted isn't always minimized because other combinations aren't put into consideration. (And those other combinations have less space wasted)
2. I also considered some variant of Dijkstra's algorithm and just focus on minimizing the space wasted. This time however, I discovered that it doesn't always yield the minimal # of bins.

That's about it. I only tried greedy approaches so far because I was hoping there was an easy way to solve it. If there isn't, then please enlighten me. I'll accept the truth even if it hurts. Thanks!

EDIT:
I only want to know if it's solvable using another greedy approach. Also, I want to know what generic problem I can search for and learn on so that it can help me with this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a "do my homework" service. Show your code as a [mcve] and state your **specific** problem.

Comment: "the item that comes first must be placed before considering the next item" What does this condition mean exactly?

Comment: @n.m. the item the comes first must be placed in current bin before considering the next item. my bad it's unclear.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry for being vague, I edited the post. I wasn't exactly asking for a complete solution on the problem (so I figured some bare insights about my attempts would be enough). I was only looking for some tips so I can start somewhere. (But if that motive is wrong too then please tell me i'm not really sure)

Comment: You already wrote that. I'm asking what this *means*. To make the question easier, you have 2 bins of capacity 4 and you are getting these weights: 1,1,3,3. What do you do? Now the weights are 1,1,4,2. What do you do? Do you place the first two weights differently in each case? If so, what you base your decision on?

Comment: Of those bins which would be at least 95% full after taking the new weight, you choose the one that is already heaviest. If there are no such bins, all you can do is place it at random. As the previous comment shows - you cannot know whether to place the two `1` weights in the same bin, or in different bins.

Comment: @n.m. I'm confused because your question assumes there are only 2 bins, and the question is to find the min #of bins.

But anyway for the 2 cases you gave:

for 1,1,3,3 --> 1-1,3,3     thus the space wasted is (4-2)+(4-3)+(4-3) = 4

for 1,1,4,2 --> 1-1,4,2     thus the space wasted is (4-2)+0+(4-2) = 4

the minimum # of bins to use given the constraint *that you should place the item that comes first* is 3. However, since they both have the same space wasted, just choose the first correct occurrence. 


I solved another case in gnasher's post ,check it out too.

Comment: But the question says "The priority is to minimize the number of bins first." The examples can both be solved with 2 bins (and no wasted capacity) but you are using 3.

Comment: @WeatherVane Hmm, that was supposed to clarify that the main priority is to minimize bins, not minimize the space wasted. The constraint however should still be followed, so it should come first. (does that make sense or should I edit the post?) But yeah, although you can solve 1,1,3,3 as 1-3,1-3 to have 2 bins, since it doesn't follow the constraint then it's not valid.

Comment: Your algorithm seems to be "place in the current bin until there is no capacity", but in the second example of 1,1,4,2 you could place `2` in the first bin, without looking forwards.

Comment: OK, replace "two bins" with "many bins" in my question. Now can you answer it? I don't see you are trying to answer it. The question is simple: where does the second weight go, to the new bin or to the same bin as the first one? How do you decide?

Comment: @n.m. I'm not sure if this fixes it but what if I define a better  'spacewasted' function. Say this function is piecewise and has the following behavior: 0, if <=5% space is wasted; (W*%space wasted)^2, if >5%.  For the 1,1,3,3 example, that means I'd choose 1-1,3,3 bin groupings instead of 1,1-3,3. Thanks for your continued responses btw I really appreciate it.

Comment: @n.m It only means that the order of how you give the input matters. For instance in the input 1,2,3,2. It means you should place 1 inside a bin before placing the first occurrence '2'. If the condition did not exist, then I could've simply grouped 1-3, 2-2 together to be optimal. But since order matters, I group it this way: 1-2,3,2.

Comment: Now I'm utterly confused. You have 1,1 incoming. You don't see what comes after that. What exactly makes you decide to put these weights in different bins? If you do put them in different bins, why won't you return to bin 1 when a weiht of 3 comes in?

Comment: Let's just say that you lock the bin after using it, so you can't return to it. @n.m. Also the "before considering the next item" in my condition doesn't mean that you can't see the next item. I think the better way to put it is "before placing the next item". You already know the entire input sequence 1,1,3,3 before commencing the solution. I'm really sorry for the confusion agghhhh xD

Comment: "you lock the bin after using it" That's a **very** different thing from "the item that comes first must be placed before considering the next item." I recommend you delete this question and ask a new one, using the correct wording for the condition, because all the preceding discussion just makes zero sense once you change the terms completely.

Comment: Or perhaps just delete the question and ask nothing, because the new question is completely trivial. If the weight fits in the current bin, put it in the current bin. If it does not, start a new bin. That's all that is there to it.There is no situation where some other decision would lead to a better packing.

Comment: @n.m. Before I delete the question, I have one last. As I've said earlier, say I modified the spacewasted function as follows: 0, if <=5% space is wasted; (W*%space wasted)^2, if >5%. There would be cases that yields to a better packing right? As in the sample groupings 1-1,3,3 and 1,1-3,3. The former would be better. How do I deal with this then?

Answer (score 1):

"the item that comes first must be placed before considering the next item" - this means you are stuffed. All you can do is take guesses.

I'd say as each item arrives, you check first if there is a bin that would go from >5% waste to ≤5% waste and put it there, then you check if there is a bin where the item fits and put it there, and if it doesn't fit anywhere you put it into a fresh bin.

The whole criterion seems a bit ludicrous. Why would three bins filled at 96%, 94.5%, 94.5% be worse than three bins filled at 95%, 95% and 95%? Basically this means that you want to fill bins just above 95%, because if you fill one to 100% it could mean another bin falls below 95%. That is until you need a new bin because you have all these almost 5% gaps.

Comment: Yes the 5% criterion is just some kind of preference ( can't think of any other real life example). When there are 3 bins that are all at 95%, then *technically* no space is wasted. You'd prefer this over the 96%, 94.5%, 94.5% sample (where 1% space is wasted). 

also, regarding the "all you can do is take guesses", does that mean there is no optimal approach for this? or can I still use a dynamic programming approach?

Comment: I don't see how dynamic programming can help if the decision for what bin an item will go into has to be decided before seeing subsequent items. When looking at item `N` you can't change where items `1` through `N-1` go and you don't know anything about items `N+1` through the last item.  So I think as @gnasher729 said: you're stuffed.